# Finding the current in a parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Two resistors are joined as shown. The top resistor receives a current of 3 A. What is the current in the other resistor? What is the current that enters at junction A? I'm confused on how the two currents are 3A and 1A because I thought in a series circuit all the currents are the same. Why is the answer to the current entering junction A 4 A and not 1 A?
[image]

Comment: To be clear, this is a parallel circuit, not a series one. Does that help? :)

Comment: You are right: if two resistor are in series the current is the same, but those are in parallel...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two resistors are in parallel. This means that at $A$ the current splits between them relating to their reistance. So the current throw the top resistor is $3\,A$ and throw the bottom resistor is $1 \,A$. If we use Kirchhoff's current law which states, that in any node (like $A$) the current flowing into the node is equal to the current flowing out of it. You have $1+3=4\,A$ flowing out of node $A$ and thus must have $4\,A$ flowing into the node.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parallel circuit, not a series one. So the currents not need be the same, but the potencial difference is the same instaed. In a series circuit the current is the same but the potencial is different in the many elements of the circuit. You can think about this like the current is a flow of water, since is parallel, the current (the flow) "divides" in both sides, going more water (current) in the way with lesser resistance.